# If $y_{n}=f(x_{n})$ then $\{y_{n}\}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have this problem statement:

*Consider the function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R \ni f(x)=x$, and any convergent sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ to any number $a\in\Bbb R$ i.e., $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=a$*

*Is the sequence $\{y_{n}\}$ convergent, where $y_{n}=f(x_{n})$?*

This is solution I have:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=y_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=a$

So I conclude that the sequence $\{y_{n}\}$ is convergent.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally, if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is any continuous function, and $x_n\in\Bbb R$ a convergent sequence, then $y_n=f(x_n)$ is convergent and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n).$$
This is in fact one way of defining continuity.